# Matching melodies

Tags: c++, .net, audio, comparison

I'm trying to figure out an approach to compare two melodies to see how similar they are. Timbre doesn't matter. So if I had two recordings, one of a flute playing Happy Birthday and one of a Trumpet playing the same thing at the same pitches and tempo, it should consider them a match.

Is there a .NET or C++ library that can do this? If not, can someone give me an idea of what techniques I would need to do something like this?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad.  Stack Overflow is intended to help you solve specific, directed, programming problems.  Complete algorithm and solution development is pretty out of scope.  Go try something, do some research, and come back here when you have a specific question about a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aubio](http://aubio.org/) has a C++ interface and several methods for performing pitch detection.

Since you are assuring that pitch and tempo will be the same and you seem to be ruling out harmonies, you can measure pitch over time and compare the two results.

Your comparison algorithm will require trial-and-error refinement.  Keep in mind:

- noise, timbre, and volume fluctuations can make the pitch at any moment a subjective topic
- real-world performers can have *similar* pitch and tempo, but it's unlikely that they'll be perfectly the same.
- The two songs may not start at the same moment in the recording.